# What are nullable rules when calling Java from Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, nullable

Why does Kotlin in one case infer type returned from Java to be nullable and in another case it is can be either, nullable or non-nullable?

I've checked both `HashMap.get` and `JsonNode.get` and I could not identify any @NotNull-like annotations neither in calsses nor anywhere in inheritance chain. What makes Kotlin treating those 2 calls differently?

I have read documentation https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types but it explanation use "Platform Types" without explaining what those are and it does not explain differences in behavior anyway.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode

private fun docType(node: JsonNode, map: java.util.HashMap<String,String>) {
    val x: JsonNode = node.get("doc_type")  // DOES compile and can throw NPE at runtime
    val y: JsonNode? = node.get("doc_type") // DOES compile and Kotlin's type system will force you to check for null
    val z: String = map.get("a")            // ERROR: Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
}
```

Comment: I think _node.get("doc_type")_ will never return _null_. Instead _NullNode_, a subclass of _JsonNode_ would be returned for a non-existing lookup value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kotlin provides seamless interoperability with Java, without compromising its own null-safety... almost. One exception is that Kotlin assumes that *all* types that are defined in Java are not-null.

To understand, let's look at `JsonNode.get()`

#### Platform types

```java
public JsonNode get(String fieldName) { return null; }
```

Note that `JsonNode` is defined in Java, and is therefore a [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types) - and Kotlin does not 'translate' it to `JsonNode?`, even though that would be technically correct (because in Java all types are nullable).

When calling Java from Kotlin, [for convenience](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/why-doesnt-kotlin-default-to-nullable-for-java-types/16753) it's assumed that platform types are non-nullable. If this wasn't the case, you would *always* have to check that any instance of any platform type is not null.

So, to answer your question about what a 'platform type' is, it's a term that means

- some type that is defined in an external target language,
- you can't mention it explicitly in Kotlin code (but there's probably a synonymous Kotlin equivalent),
- and we're going to assume that it's non-nullable for convenience.
- Also the notation is `<type>!`, for example `String!` - which we can take to mean `String or String?`

#### Nullability annotations

The closest Java equivalent of Kotlin's nullable `?` symbol are [nullability annotations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations), which the Kotlin compiler can parse and take into account. However, none are used on `JsonNode` methods. And so Kotlin will quite happily assume that `node.get("")` will return `JsonNode`, not `JsonNode?`.

As you noted, there are none defined for `HashMap.get(...)`.

So how does Kotlin know that `map.get("a")` returns a nullable type?

#### Type inference

[Type inference](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-inference.html#type-inference) can't help. The (Java) method signature

```java
public V get(Object key) {
  //...
}
```

indicates that a `HashMap<String, String>` should return `String`, not `String?`. Something else must be going on...

#### Mapped types

For most Java types, Kotlin will just use the definition as provided. But for some, Kotlin decides to treat them specially, and completely replace the Java definition with its own version.

You can see [the list of mapped types in the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#mapped-types). And while `HashMap` isn't in there, `Map` is. And so, when we're writing Kotlin code, `HashMap` doesn't inherit from `java.util.Map` - because it's mapped to `kotlin.collections.Map`

> Aside: in fact if you try and use `java.util.Map` you'll get a warning [image: code that uses java.util.Map with an IntelliJ warning: This class shouldn't be used in Kotlin. Use kotlin.collections.Map or kotlin.collections.MutableMap instead.]

So if we look at the code for the `get` function that `kotlin.collections.Map` defines, [we can see that it returns a nullable value type](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/6fc27c22f44d8051bf2e89f1657c0d9741c281c0/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Collections.kt#L320)

```kotlin
/**
* Returns the value corresponding to the given [key], or `null` if such a key is not present in the map.
*/
public operator fun get(key: K): V?
```

And so the Kotlin compiler can look at `HashMap.get(...)` and deduce that, because it's implementing `kotlin.collections.Map.get(...)`, the returned value *must* be a nullable value, which in our case is `String?`.

#### Workaround:  External annotations

For whatever reason, Jackson doesn't use the nullability annotations that would solve this problem. Fortunately IntelliJ provides a workaround that, while not as strict, will provide helpful warnings: [external annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/external-annotations.html).

Once I follow the instructions...

1. Alt+Enter → 'Annotate method...'

   [image]
2. Select 'Nullable' annotation

   [image]
3. Save `annotations.xml`

Now `node.get("")` will show an warning.

[image]

This annotation isn't visible to the Kotlin compiler, so it can only be a warning - not a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

[`java.util.HashMap.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-) implements the interface method [`java.util.Map.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-). Kotlin maps some Java types to its own types internally. The full table of these mappings is available [on the website](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#mapped-types). In our particular case, we see that `java.util.Map` gets mapped internally to [`kotlin.collections.Map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/), whose [`get`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/get.html) function looks like

> ```
> abstract operator fun get(key: K): V?
> ```

So as far as Kotlin is concerned, `java.util.Map` is just a funny name for `kotlin.collections.Map`, and all of the methods on `java.util.Map` actually have the signatures of the corresponding ones from `kotlin.collections.Map` (which are basically the same except with correct null annotations).

So while the first two `node.get` calls are Java calls and return platform types, the third one (as far as Kotlin is concerned) is actually calling a method Kotlin understands: namely, `get` from *its own* `Map` type. And that type has an explicit nullability annotation already available, so Kotlin can confidently say that that value *can* be `null` and needs to be checked.

Comment: The question author is using `java.util.HashMap`, not `java.util.Map`. I don't think `HashMap` is a mapped type, it's a platform type. Mapped types are used when Kotlin has re-implemented a class, but Kotlin doesn't re-implement `HashMap` - it's aliased to Java `HashMap`  https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/6fc27c22f44d8051bf2e89f1657c0d9741c281c0/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/collections/TypeAliases.kt#L15

Comment: Right, but the function OP is calling is from the interface `Map`. The exact implementation of the map is irrelevant; Kotlin has already decided that *all* `Map.get` functions on any valid `Map` implementation are nullable.